# Upgrade To Windows 8 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have purchased the key but before I go with the installation, need to ask a question.

Do I need to perform the partition again for my drives in my laptop while upgrading it from Windows 7 to Windows 8?

I don't want to perform the partition again on all the drives as I don't want to loose my data.

Can only the C drive format will do to upgrade it to Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 7 can be upgraded directly to Windows 8 without any of your data or supported applications being uninstalled. Just run the installer from within Windows 7.  I am sure this question has been asked several times we expect some level of research on a subject before a question is asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step graphical tutorial of how to do that:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-you-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-8/7ad17060-3bbe-473c-a795-6f2b13c6d3a9

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-partition your hard disk again. Partitions are OS-independent. You can install Windows 8 over Windows 7 in C: drive.

1. If you're performing normal upgrade (with default option),. Even your installed applications will be preserved. Means, you'll find your existing compatible applications installed when you'll boot Windows 8.
2. If you're doing fresh upgrade/install, you'll find fresh default Windows 8 without any third-party software installed. You can find Users etc folder created by previous OS in `C:\Windows.old` folder. And, other folders of C: drive would be intact.

So, in any case, **you won't loose your files from even C: drive, loosing data from other drive is a remote thing.**

**Warning:** With the installation from boot media, if you choose to format C: drive, you'll loose data from C: drive. Formating C: drive isn't mandatory.